# Create Own Adapter in Android?

Tags: android

How to Create Own Adapter in Android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new class that extends the abstract class [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and then implement the following methods:

- getCount
- getItem
- getItemId
- getView

You can also [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android%20custom%20adapter%20tutorial) for adapter tutorials. I'd recommend:

1. Reading the [Binding to Data with AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)
2. Getting started on an implementation as described above
3. Asking questions when you have problems with your implementation

The implementation will depend on the underlying data you are trying to represent, so a one-line question is really not going to cut it.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of Custom Adapter [tutorials](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) out there.