# Android - Passing multiple values into an adapter

Tags: android, adapter

My `main.xml` has 2 edit text for the user to insert values. And my `custom_list_item.xml` has a text view and an edit text. The input of the user would be inserted into the text view and edit text respectively.

However, currently I am only able to pass 1 value into the adapter. How can I pass the other value over to the adapter?

main.java

```
public class main extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
FancyAdapter aa = null;

Button calculate;
EditText result;
String total;
String name;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.noteList);
    aa = new FancyAdapter();

    final EditText price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
    final EditText name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                 int position, long arg3) {

           aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    Button btnSimple = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);        

    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
            int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            name = name1.getText().toString();

            if(position == 0)
            {
                totalPrice = totalPrice * 1.07;
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);
                System.out.println(total);
                //result.setText(total); 
            }
            else
            {
                totalPrice = (totalPrice * 1.1)*1.07;
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);
                System.out.println(total);
                //result.setText(total); 
            }
            noteList.add(0, total); 
            System.out.println(total);
            name1.setText("");
            price.setText("");
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });        

}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Button calculate;
    EditText price;
    EditText result;

    FancyAdapter()
    {
        super(main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;     

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        }

        //((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nametv)).setText(noteList.get(position));
        ((EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.result)).setText(noteList.get(position));
        return (row);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just send a whole string to the adapter. Then split the string up accordingly. You may want to add a colon or some identifier to split.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Adapter by extending BaseAdapter class, Below are more reference for the same

[adapter tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327)

[Same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561727/create-own-adapter-in-android)

Comment: I would like to try to stick to the original codes if possible with additional codes

Comment: so you want to stick with your code, or want to solve your problem. I will suggest you to use BaseAdapter class,, it gives more features and once you will do that you will have some experience on List, It is good to use BaseAdapter class and create own adapter, if want to show multiple views in listview.