# Adding attributes in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a problem with my ListView. I want it to contain different values from my object.
My object Item has 4 attributes:

```
String name;
int number;
int price;
boolean check;
```

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(new Item("hej", 1, 1, false));
list.add(new Item("farvel", 2, 2, true));
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.tv, list));

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Now i want the true/false to be linked to my checkbox in this XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would really like your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own adapter to do that.

Basically, you extend one of the adapter classes and override (as necessary) the following methods:

```
getCount
getItem
getItemId
getView
```

There are several guides/tutorials floating around:

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5561813/1105376)

[Adapter Tutorial 1](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327)

[Custom ArrayAdapter Example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Good luck!