# Problems changing the background colors in an android listview without clicking

Tags: android, android-listview

When my application loads, I need some(not necessarily all) of the items in my list view to change their backgrounds without clicking on the ones I need. I know the method to change background, but I don't know how to extract the views from the ListView to do that.

I looked at this question and the answer did not work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650692/how-to-change-background-color-list-view-item-without-click-on-any-of-them

Here is some of my code:

```
    mApprovalList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.approvals_array)));
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                                        R.layout.approvals_list, 
                                        immApprovalList);       
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);       
    ListView lv = getListView();
    Log.v(String.valueOf(lv.getChildCount()), "count");
```

Also, that "log" returns 0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a custom adapter and have it set the backgrounds to whatever color you'd like. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5561813/458968

Then use

```
MyCustomAdapter customAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, mApprovalList);

setListAdapter(customAdapter);
```

in your onCreate method.